# How to exclude a particular string from set of server logs

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am new to Splunk and would appreciate if anyone helps me on this.
I would like to know the splunk query- for properties that have this log "not found in cache and enable, trying to return from" and NOT have "No content returned for" , this particular log
These strings are on a different line

INFO - Service - Getting content=tItem for property=79551

INFO - Service - content=Item "not found in cache and enable, trying to return from",property=79551

INFO - Service - "Returning content from" resource=Item property=79551

INFO - Service - content=Item "not found in cache and is healthy, trying to return from",property=79551

INFO - Service - "No content returned for" property=79551, content=Item

sumarising once-more the condition
include "not found in cache and enable, trying to return from" and exclude "No content returned for"
need to have such properties as the final result.

Can someone kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Excluding a string from search results is just a matter of using the `NOT` operator with the undesired string.

```
index=foo "not found in cache and enable, trying to return from" NOT "No content returned for"
```

Comment: i used that above query shared , but it not working its not excluding the second part 
ALL these logs which i have shared above are separate logs ,just FYI

Comment: Searching for a specific string will exclude any events which do not include that string so you should never see any "No content returned for" events.  You say the logs are separate, but are they related?  If so, how?

Comment: yes all these logs which i have shared are separate and related because its for the same property

Comment: i want to get the property , that have  "not found in cache and enable, trying to return from". and that same property should not be containing this "No content returned for" 

As all these logs are separate simply giving NOT is not working